# Get Autogenerated Id in Firestore Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

The structure of my database is as follows:

Rooms>autogeneratedId>postId

In my url the postId is present:
for e.g. www.abc.com/post.html?xyz123

the xyz123 is my post Id

so considering the above scenario, I am able to perform the where query as follows:

```
var link = window.location.href;
var postId = adLink.split('?');
db.collection("Room").where("postId", "==", postId[1]).get()
```

this query finds my item, the thing is I need to get the auto generated document Id inside which the postId exists

Comment: Which database are your using? Firestore or the Real Time Database? It is not crystal clear for me (despite the fact that your code contains Firestore syntax).

Comment: I am using firestore.